# "Could not create Makefile" when trying to install mysql gem

Tags: mysql, ruby

I am running Ruby v2.3.3 on Debian 9.6. I executed this command in the terminal: `sudo gem install mysql`.

This gave me an error.

```
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

Here's the full text of the error: https://pastebin.com/raw/HZcL2UtF

Here's the contents of `mkmf.log`: https://pastebin.com/raw/Bki5e9tT

Why can't I install the `mysql` gem? How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually that means that you don't have required mysql libs on your system.

Try execute:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev libmysqlclient16
```

Then run mysql gem installation again:

```
sudo gem install mysql
```